Get "http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/query_range?direct00&step=30000ms": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
I'm encountering a timeout error when trying to run a query in Grafana using Loki. The error message is as follows:
context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

I've set the limit to a high value (1,000,000) to ensure I capture all logs.
Screenshot of error:



Open the configuration file located at /etc/grafana/grafana.ini and navigate to the [dataproxy] section. Increase the timeout setting to 360 (which equals 360 seconds).

Restart the Grafana server by running the command:
systemctl restart grafana-server

In the Grafana UI, go to the Data Sources section, select the Loki data source, and update the timeout setting to 360 (360 seconds).


Following these steps should resolve the error you encountered.
